# How to set scalacOptions used by SBT when compiling Build.scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to set/append to `scalacOptions` used by SBT when compiling `Build.scala`. Someone on my team copied a bit of code from Akka's `Build.scala` and the result was a bunch of deprecated warnings and a feature warning.

```
$ reload
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/xxx/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/xxx/yyy/zzz/project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/xxx/yyy/zzz/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[warn] there were 3 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] two warnings found
```

Things I have tried

1. Add `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-feature")` to `build.sbt`. I was hoping this would get loaded before `Build.scala` was compiled.
2. Already had `scalacOptions ++= Seq(...., "-unchecked", "-feature")` in `Build.scala`
3. Attempt to set `scalacOptions` prior to `reload` but it appears to be discarded

   ```
   $ ;set scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature", "-deprecated") ;reload
   [info] Defining zzz/*:scalacOptions
   [info] The new value will be used by zzz/compile:scalacOptions
   [info] Reapplying settings...
   [info] Set current project to zzz (in build file:/Users/xxx/yyy/zzz/)
   [info] Loading global plugins from /Users/xxx/.sbt/0.13/plugins
   [info] Loading project definition from /Users/xxx/yyy/zzz/project
   [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/xxx/yyy/zzz/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
   [warn] there were 3 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
   [warn] there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
   [warn] two warnings found
   [warn] Discarding 1 session setting.  Use 'session save' to persist session settings.
   ```

Through much blood sweat I was able to find the cause of the deprecated warnings, but I can't find the cause of the feature warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive), which means the `Build.scala` in `project` directory is build by another definition in its parent directory or `build.sbt` in the `project` directory.

Therefore you have to create `build.sbt` in `project` directory. In the `project/build.sbt` you should be able to set `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-feature")`.

Comment: I had `build.sbt` in the wrong place. This worked when I moved `build.sbt` from root directory  to `project/build.sbt`

Comment: @drstevens you're right, it should be in `project/build.sbt`, I've updated my answer. If you wanted to create `Build.scala` you would create one in `project/project/Build.scala`.